# Automatic mounting of NAS drive fails

Tags: networking, mount, fstab

I have set-up my RPi to automatically mount a NAS drive. My /etc/fstab file looks like:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p5  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p6  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
//192.168.2.11/Videos /home/pi/NASvideos cifs username=NASUSER,password=NASPAS,iocharset=utf8 0 0    
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, so no using swapon|off from here on, use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

When I start up the RPi and type in `ls NASvideos` there is no output while the Videos folder on the NAS drive contains files. However, when I then manually mount the drive by typing in `sudo mount -a` followed by `ls NASvideos` it now shows the files. I don't understand why I can manually mount the drive like this but it doesn't do it automatically at boot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the RPi not auto-mounting might have to do with the network not yet being up when it runs the /etc/fstab file (as suggested by user KenR). One can resolve this issue by writing a short script that mounts all drives that is run automatically each time the RPi boots:

Create script in /etc/init.d:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/mountscript
```

Add the following (or similar) text to the file:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/mountscript 

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          Mounting of all drives
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Simple script to mount drives at boot
# Description:       Added 30jan 2014
### END INIT INFO

#Now mount all drives
sudo mount -a
echo "All drives mounted"
```

Make script executable:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/mountscript
```

Test starting the script:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mountscript start
```

Register script to be run at start-up:

```
sudo update-rc.d mountscript defaults
```

Reboot the RPi and see if the NAS drive is mounted:

```
sudo reboot
ls NAMEOFDRIVE
```

If you ever want to remove the script from start-up

```
sudo update-rc.d -f  mountscript remove
```

See more on writing start-up scripts here: http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/2012/06/raspberry-pi-run-program-at-start-up.html

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Was trying quite a few things, but this finally helped.

Answer (score 2):

Setting it to automount worked for me

Append `_netdev,x-systemd.automount` to your options

For example:

```
//192.168.2.11/Videos /home/pi/NASvideos cifs username=NASUSER,password=NASPAS,iocharset=utf8,_netdev,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar problem. The problem, in my case, was that the network was
not 'UP' when the pi booted so the fstab mount failed without any messages.
This prevented my script from running. I solved it in my script by adding the following few
lines at the beginning...
while true ; do

```
if ! ( ping -c 1 My_ROUTER_IP ) > /dev/null

then

   echo "network is NOT up so wait"

   sleep 2

else

   echo "Network is UP"

   sudo mount -a

   break

fi
```

done

Hope that helps
KenR

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I decided to write a script that is run at start-up based on your idea, see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this suggestion, and it trashed my Pi. The boot process failed with a message "You are in emergency mode" among others, and went into an infinite loop. So I could not complete the boot process and get control to reverse these changes. Thank goodness for backups!
A simpler solution that worked for me is to use cron, with a single schedule entry:
@reboot sudo mount -a

This is using Raspian version 9 (Stretch).
Posted Feb 22, 2019

Comment: Which suggestion? Do you mean one of the previous answers? If that's the case then you should not have added this as a new answer, but as a comment on that answer.

Comment: You should take note that using `cron` to start jobs at boot is not the best way because [Crontab suddenly doesn't start jobs](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94518/79866).

Answer (score 0):

I used mountscript as outlined above but it still didn't work on boot while working fine if executed manually.

I eventually added $network to the Required-Start line in the script and it now works

Comment: It might have to do with your rpi not waiting for the network on boot. Check that in your rpi settings.