# Crontab suddenly doesn't start jobs

Tags: raspbian-stretch, python-3, cron, systemd-startup

I'm suddenly having crontab issues, I didn't do anything other than change the script names and then change them in crontab as well so they all natch, the scripts work if I start them manually, so i'm assuming crontab doesn't start them for whatever reason. The scripts launch two python discord bots with the discord.py async branch which both use infinite event loops

crontab entries:
[image: Crontab Entry Screenshot]

1st sh script that runs with the bash interpreter:
[image: launchjuvia.py]

2nd sh script that also runs with the bash interpreter:
[image]

I am at a loss here so any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please don't use pictures for text output. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Comment: Noted, will do in future posts

Answer (score 4):

You can help yourself by collecting any error messages that are generated when `cron` runs your scripts. As you're aware, your shell will send error messages to the `stderr` stream when they occur. When you run the program from your terminal screen, this `stderr` stream goes to your terminal, and you see it. However, your `cron` job does NOT run under your userid, and its `stderr` stream does NOT go to the screen.

Fortunately, Linux allows us to "redirect" the `stderr` stream, and we can redirect it to a file on our system. Doing this is very simple, but the command itself will seem arcane until you study it for a bit. You can redirect the error messages from your `cron` jobs by changing your `crontab` file as follows:

```
@reboot /home/pi/launchjuvia.sh >> /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1 
@reboot /home/pi/launchfuta.sh >> /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1
```

After reboot, you can inspect the file `/home/pi/cronjoblog`, and read any error messages. If you have trouble deciphering the error messages, feel free to post them here & we'll try to help.

A coupla' other notes:

1. I don't think you need to call out `bash` in your `crontab`.
2. I don't understand what you're doing with the first line in your `crontab`. If you're trying to schedule a `reboot` recall that `sudo` is normally required (i.e. `sudo reboot` instead of `reboot`). In any case, I'd recommend you resolve the errors in your script first, then tackle your scheduled reboots once you have that sorted.
3. @Ingo's answer also has merit. `systemd` is technically superior to `cron` in some respects - an important one being that it has knowledge of resource availability during the boot process. However, `cron` is (IMHO) simpler, and inserting a `sleep` command in your `crontab` will usually resolve resource availability issues. For example:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 10; /home/pi/launchjuvia.sh >> /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1
```

This will postpone execution of your shell script for 10 seconds after `cron` starts, and by then the resources needed for successful execution may be available. You may need to experiment a bit to find the "best" value for sleep time.

Comment: Alright. I see. Well I have to use bash because sh complains about paths, unfortunately adding the sleep part does not solve the problem, i've already got stderr redirected but nothing appears on my files, which tells me that the python modules do not run at all. As for the reboot line you were right, i forgot to put sudo in which explains why it wasn't restarting

Comment: @Myronaz OK... but your script contains a shebang for `sh`, so why are you calling `bash` ?  And I just noticed that the first line of your script is `cd /`... why do you do that? As far as the redirect, maybe try adding this after your shebang line: `>&2 echo "test stderr redirect"`

Comment: @Myronaz: Also remember that the "cron user" does not have the same environment vars as you do working from the command line. Therefore, it's a good habit to use full paths for all commands and file locations in cron jobs.

Comment: *"Fortunately, Linux allows us to 'redirect' the stderr stream"* -> Would be more accurate to say "the shell", or more specifically `bash` or `sh`.  Different shells in fact use different syntax for this (and e.g. `bash` includes sugar that `sh` doesn't, such as `&>`).  What you've used is standard POSIX shell, which is good because it is the normal case on the Pi.

Comment: @goldilocks: [Good point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351403/linux-crontab-which-shell-am-i-using)

Answer (score 2):

You are using crontab to start programs on boot with option `@reboot`. In `man 5 crontab` you can read:

> Please note that startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, is the time when the cron(8) daemon startup.  In particular, it may  be  before  some  system  daemons, or other facilities, were startup. This is due to the boot order sequence of the machine.

On Raspian Stretch starting system daemons and services are managed by **systemd** and it starts them parallel only controlled by dependencies. So a boot order sequence is not defined with systemd. If you change something, for example renaming services or installing additional services or removing some, then the boot order may change.

So it is possible that scripts suddenly doesn't start anymore with **cron** because they are missing services they need to run. These services are starting later now.

To avoid this problem you should use systemd unit files to make clean services managed by systemd with dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the actual /etc/crontab file, shouldn't there be a field after the day-of-the-week that specifies the username under which the command should be run? See man crontab for help, and be sure not to confuse the actual /etc/crontab file with a user crontab file. They are different.